# It is possible to code this on PHP?

Tags: php, .net, vb.net, hwid

i coded some vb.net application, for security i use HWID security method...

vb.net code to generate unique key is:

```
Dim hwid As String = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.User.Value
```

it will return some unique key for every pc like this

> S-1-2324-34242FDF-SDWQ3Q-Q3WR4CWRWCE1321SXS32

currently i am learning & developing PHP scripts...

i want to know it is possible to generate the same unique key using PHP???

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down.

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

Is a method that returns the current user.

```
.User.Value
```

Is actually calling:

```
.User.toString()
```

The method is actually:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.toString()
```

This is simply the [User's Security Identifier (SID)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier).

Running `wmic useraccount get name,sid` returns all the SIDs found on the machine.

[image]

Now, what does this mean for PHP? Well since PHP is ran on the server only, I doubt this number will change based on which visitor visits. So using this number in PHP is pointless, as it will always be the same.

A better approach for generating a random ID is [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

Check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier#Decoding_Machine_SID) for information on how this SID is derived from the registry.

Comment: thanks for your reply..so php is server side...  so it is possible by javascript /vbscript on client area to get the unique key....

Comment: No that would not be possible with JavaScript. If the user is running Internet Explorer, and has allowed VBScript, you could get the SID [with a VBScript](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/12/03/how-can-i-determine-the-sid-for-a-user-account.aspx).

Comment: If you're trying to ban or do something with this SID, **don't**. This is on the client-side and therefore should not be used for authentication or validation of any sort. A better option would be sessions (cookies), www-authenticate, or even a direct IP check. (Note that IP can be faked in some instances too)